# How to add personal android projects to my CV to get into Android job market

Tags: android

I am an experienced Java Programmer. 1 year back I started android programming and published 3 Apps into the market. But these all are my personal projects. Now I want get into the android job market. As my android experience is not corporate experience does the companies consider this? How to add these android projects to my CV to get into Android job market?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not the best question, but what's up with every answer getting a downvote? +1 to everyone for the effort.

Comment: according to [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), Programmers Q&A are "**not about** ...résumé help" => this question is off-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Experience gained making those apps are more important.**

It would be a waste of space to simply list the applications that you have worked on in the past and simply leave it at that.  It doesn't matter if these are personal applications or commercial applications.

What is important is the quality of the software that you have produced, and what you have learned in the process.

If you list these attributes first and then lastly present your applications as "proof", then it should be inconsequential if these were commercially created or paid for apps or personal projects.

IMO the most important aspects of writing any software for that matter are:

- **Results** - are you proud of your achievements of these personal apps, are they of a quality you are happy for an interviewer to evaluate your skill based on these applications.  If not then **DO NOT** list them.
- **Methods used for Quality Assurance** - Did you write JUnit Tests, perform end user testing with multiple emulators in various screen resolutions / orientations.  Does the software work without crashing, handle exceptions correctly etc.
- **What you have learned creating your personal apps** - What technology did you use, what have you learned that can be applied to your next commercial app.

If you can answer the above questions in your resume (very quickly in bullet form), and express that you went through the same process as you would have for a commercial app.

You will then be showing clearly that you have relevant experience.

Answer (score 3):

1. Come up with a company name (and make a web page for it)
2. Call yourself the owner
3. Add the products to your CV under that company

Because, after all, if you are writing software for the android market (especially if you are selling them), then you **are** your own company, and you **do** have 'commercial' experience.

Dont undersell your 'personal' projects just because they arent developed within a cubicle farm.  Being able to conceptualize, implement, and ultimately sell your own software is a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

**So the question do you want to target Android Market only or Android + Java?**

If you are an experienced Java developer, I would say mention your experience as Java developer and then add your experience as an Android developer. Try to indicate that you are making a shift. This way you will have a professional experience as well as your own project to indicate you are trying to make switch. Three projects are good enough to get into Android Market. Even one is good enough. **You just have to sell yourself.** I probably would list them on the top since that is where I am focusing now.

I had a similar change of career from C++ development to web development. Initially I had listed only one of my PHP projects and my resume was a mixture of C++ and PHP. Gradually got a couple of more projects that I added and then I just totally focused it on Web Development. I still mentioned my C++ experience. I had better success with my web developer resume although the C++ market wasn't that bad at all.

**Should you list your personal project?**

Absolutely. As Justin answer says if you are proud of it, mention it! You must! Believe it or not I got sold by stuff that I did personally years ago when I was a student. I was proud of it so I mentioned it. One could have said, why bother mentioning such thing, and they wouldn't be that wrong.

I think it is important to highlight both your experiences Java + Android. And you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Create a section at the bottom that lists what you did.  If anything is piblicly available, mention it there.  Also include all the buzzwords to get it by HR and the auto filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it as your Pet-Projects and put it under your educational qualification before professional experience to highlight it in same order.